# How to get distinct values of each property independently

Tags: c#, performance, linq, distinct-values

I have *large yielded collection* and I would like to get *distinct values* of each property independently:

```
IEnumerable<MyClass> collection = ...;

var prop1Values = collection.Select(i => i.Prop1).Distinct();
var prop2Values = collection.Select(i => i.Prop2).Distinct();
var prop3Values = collection.Select(i => i.Prop3).Distinct();
```

How to get it without enumerating the collection *multiple times*? Looking for most intuitive solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try do it in a single `foreach` with a help of `HashSet<T>`s:

```
//TODO: put the right types for TypeOfProp1, TypeOfProp2, TypeOfProp3
var prop1Values = new HashSet<TypeOfProp1>(); 
var prop2Values = new HashSet<TypeOfProp2>();
var prop3Values = new HashSet<TypeOfProp3>();

foreach (var item in collection) {
  prop1Values.Add(item.Prop1);
  prop2Values.Add(item.Prop2);
  prop3Values.Add(item.Prop3);
}
```